# ldap server query user information (reject queries)

Tags: linux, ldap, ldap-query, radius

How to configure ldap server to that it reject queries from anonymous users and also allow users found in the ldap datbase to access and search the database.

Comment: You need to tell us which LDAP server is being used as they are almost all unique in how this is done.

Comment: Using openldap on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: nsslapd-allow-anonymous-access
nsslapd-allow-anonymous-access: rootdse
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Identity_Management_Guide/disabling-anon-binds.html